# CPP MediaFoundation - mp4 Filesize reduces

Tags: c++, video, mp4, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I am using Media Foundation APIs to Read one mp4 file frame by frame and  manipulate some pixels and to save again as mp4, But when am saving the file size of mp4 file reduces (if  i use 3000kb video result will be 2800 )

using input type and output type as like this

```
    MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO inputType  = { MFMediaType_Video, MFVideoFormat_RGB32 };
    MFT_REGISTER_TYPE_INFO outputType = { MFMediaType_Video, MFVideoFormat_H264  };

    if( false == g_bMFTFactoryRegistered )
    {
        hResult = MFTRegisterLocal( &g_MFTFactory, MFT_CATEGORY_VIDEO_ENCODER, L"MFTFactory", 0, 1, &inputType  , 1, &outputType );
```

How to make source and destination size same??
somebody please help me

Answer (score 0):

You re-compress video and this changes the bitstream, hence you cannot make it the same size exactly. Your output depends on video encoder settings where you have a flexibility to define output profile, level, bitrate etc. Your attempt to copy that from source video might get you close with input and output sizes but anyway due to re-compression process the sizes will differ, and it is also likely that original image quality (detail) will be lost to some extent.

Comment: I have tried  hResult = pMediaTypeOut->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, 0xFFFFFFFF) to maximize the bitrate , but still the size is less

Comment: Is there any helpful link ?